# PayPal IPN not triggering Order Status updates

Tags: payment, paypal, ce-1.8.0.0, order-status

I'm setting up my first Magento system, using 1.8.0.0, running on a HostGator Windows server.

I've configured IPN on our PayPal account.  However, the payments never get communicated to Magento, and all orders are stuck at "Pending Payment".

Currently, System->Configuration->Payment Methods ->PayPal Payments Standard is associated with the Business Sandbox email, has Payment Action set to "Sale", Sandbox Mode = "Yes", and Debug Mode = "Yes".

On PayPal's side, the IPN History shows each transaction (I've tried in both Sandbox and Production) as "Retrying".  There is no HTTP Response Code listed for any of them.

The Notification URL in PayPal shows http://www.mydomain.com:/shop/Index.php/paypal/ipn/, which appears correct to me.

After turning on error logs and debug mode for the payment method, I get a log file for my sandbox attempt entitled payment_paypal_standard.log.

The contents of the file reflect the actual sandbox order:

```
2014-01-02T18:19:13+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array

(

[request] => Array
    (
        [business] => ****
        [invoice] => 100000006
        [currency_code] => USD
        [paymentaction] => sale
        [return] => https://www.mydomain.com/shop/Index.php/paypal/standard/success/
        [cancel_return] => https://www.mydomain.com/shop/Index.php/paypal/standard/cancel/
        [notify_url] => http://www.mydomain.com:/shop/Index.php/paypal/ipn/
        [bn] => Varien_Cart_WPS_US
        [item_name] => My Shopping Cart
        [lc] => en_US
        [charset] => utf-8
        [amount] => 7.99
        [tax] => 0.00
        [shipping] => 5.00
        [discount_amount] => 0.00
        [item_number_1] => Bacon4NFHS
        [item_name_1] => Bacon - Nitrate Free Hickory Smoked 4 oz.
        [quantity_1] => 1
        [amount_1] => 2.99
        [item_number_2] => Flat Rate - Fixed
        [item_name_2] => Shipping
        [quantity_2] => 1
        [amount_2] => 5.00
        [cmd] => _cart
        [upload] => 1
        [tax_cart] => 0.00
        [discount_amount_cart] => 0.00
        [city] => recipient_city
        [country] => US
        [email] => sandbox_customer_email@test.com
        [first_name] => customer_fname
        [last_name] => customer_lname
        [zip] => customer_zip
        [state] => customer_state
        [address1] => customer_address1
        [address2] => 
        [address_override] => 1
    )

[__pid] => 5440
)
```

I'm new to both PayPal IPN and Magento, so I may be making an obvious mistake, but I've also been having a ton of problems with the Magento install that were caused by problems with the auto-installer package HostGator provided.

Why are my payments not getting recorded by Magento?

Comment: Any update here? Would be great to know.

Comment: @benmarks Sorry, no definitive answers.  If I recall correctly, we narrowed it down to an issue where the IPN notification was being sent, but failing to receive the appropriate 200 response from the server. PayPal support made a convincing case for it being an issue with the server configuration, but the hosting company (HostGator) refused to acknowledge any responsibility, and would provide no additional support. Before I left the company, we had abandoned PayPal in pursuit of a payment processor offered by our bank, but were waiting on a PCI compliance eval before we could implement.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using 'Sandbox Mode'. Are you developing on your local?

PayPal will only return an IPN response if it is DMZ (open source). There are other ways around this to play on your local, but the easiest way is to test on a live server.

Comment: please put more details. It seems that this answer does not provide specific clarification to the question.

Comment: Development is not on a local machine; it is deployed on a live web server.

Answer (score 1):

Is your notify URL correct? If your site was getting a notification you should see something like a notification array in the log just after the request.

payflow advanced result looks like below.  Express checkout is a little different looking.

```
 [result] => Array
        (
            [result] => 0
            [securetoken] => ************************
            [securetokenid] => ***************************
            [respmsg] => Approved
            [result_code] => 0
        )
```